Behaviour of spread options with multiple assets
In agricultural commodity markets there is such a thing as a "Soybean Crush Spread" defined as:
CS = (Soybean Oil Price × 11 + Soybean Meal Price / 2000 x 44) − Soybean Price
I am interested to know what kind of option would be needed to price this, as a simple spread option only takes one correlation value, whilst here there would be a larger matrix.
Also, what behaviour would CS be assumed to follow? What can this be approximated to be using some sort of expansion (Taylor?).
Thank you
